# C# Threading, 1st Task DoSomething, 2nd Task update a WinFormLabel (Realtime)?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, parallel-processing

Lets say I have Task 1:

```
private void Task1()
{
    //Here is some Code, could be any "longer" Task - 
    //For Example: Grab all words from a .txt File and fill in a List<String>
}
```

Then I have an other Task 2:

```
private void Task2(string word)
{
   //So lets say theres a Label on my WinForm..
   //Now While Task1 is grabbing the words, Task2 should fill a Label 
   //with the added 'word' (parameter) - (Task2 will be called from Task1
}
```

Actually I don't know how to make this possible, or whats the best way. On the UI I should be able to see the `Label.Text` changing (every word).. So I need to make a second Thread? How could I do this? Maybe someone could help me, cheers

**UPDATE:**

I tried it now with the Backgroundworker, but something seems to be false.. its actually not working, nothing happens on the form

Code:

```
public void CreateAndSaveAMatch(DateTime date) //That method is being called several times
{   
    //HERE IS CODE, WHICH CREATES AND SAVES A MATCH

    // Start the asynchronous operation.
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(date);

}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{      
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, Convert.ToDateTime(e.Argument).ToShortDateString());          
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = (string)e.UserState; //here on the Label I would like to show the Date
}
```

Comment: There are lots and lots of examples on how to update a WinForms control from another thread. I suggest doing a search and find the method that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: You have 3 pretty god answers, have you tried them? There are no comments from you? It should be easy to implement BackgroundWroker like it was suggested by people who answered ?

Comment: I tried it with the Backgroundworker, actually not working, I'm posting now the code

Comment: I updated now the question and put what I tried

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, if your method CreateAndSaveAMatch reports when it finishes (i.e. should change label1.Text at the end of its executions, not multiple times during its execution) whenever it is called, then it can report at its very end. If it takes longer  to complete this event, then you should move the logic of that method inside your backgroundWorker1_DoWork EventHandler, and report its result within backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted method.

Comment: Could you post the code for CreateAndSaveAMatch method, then it would be lot easier to help you?

Comment: Also without this code its not working, Now I'm trying to only show the Date, which is coming to CreateAndSaveMatch(), but its also not showing on the Label.. I put a breakpoint in the ProgressChangedEvent and its not firing, but I have set the methods and eventnames correctly

Comment: @eMi verify that you changed `WorkerReportsProgress` property to true (by default it is false)

Comment: I did of course.. Everything is exactly set like u said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, try this. This is a simple example that will show you how to solve your problem using `BackgroundWorker`. Also note that there are many other solutions. To use this example create a Form in a new project that only has a button and a label. Also note that this is a supplement of the other answers which were correct.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker createAndSaveAMatchBGW;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW = new BackgroundWorker();
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(createAndSaveAMatchBGW_DoWork);
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(createAndSaveAMatchBGW_ProgressChanged);
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(createAndSaveAMatchBGW_RunWorkerCompleted);
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.RunWorkerAsync(DateTime.Now);
        }

        void createAndSaveAMatchBGW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BackgroundWorker finished");
        }

        void createAndSaveAMatchBGW_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = ((DateTime)e.UserState).ToString("ss");
        }

        void createAndSaveAMatchBGW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //BackgroundWorker does something for a 10 seconds, each second it Reports
            BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            DateTime dt = (DateTime) e.Argument;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                dt = dt.AddSeconds(1);
                bgw.ReportProgress(0, dt);
            }
        }
    }
```

And if you report from CreateAndSave... method only once per its execution, then you can use this code:

```
BackgroundWorker createAndSaveAMatchBGW;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW = new BackgroundWorker();
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(createAndSaveAMatchBGW_DoWork);
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(createAndSaveAMatchBGW_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            createAndSaveAMatchBGW.RunWorkerAsync(DateTime.Now);
        }

        void createAndSaveAMatchBGW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = ((DateTime)e.Result).ToString();
        }

        void createAndSaveAMatchBGW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt = (DateTime) e.Argument;
            //you do something with your DateTime
            dt = dt.AddDays(10);
            e.Result = dt;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that out tomorrow..I just don't understand why you are using this For Loop

Comment: @eMi The for loop simulates what you are working in your CreateAndSaveAMatch method. You didn't provide the code for it so I'm guessing that you are doing some long time running code. Therefore, whenever you do something you want to report. That is why I have used a for loop. As I said, if you have only one result of your CreateAndSaveAMatch execution, then the logic of that should be in the createAndSaveAMatchBGW_DoWork, and you should change the label1.Text in createAndSaveAMatchBGW_RunWorkerCompleted instead of createAndSaveAMatchBGW_ProgressChanged. I'll update the code for that option.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for reporting progress from first task. Drag this component from toolbox to your form, and subscribe to `DoWork` and `ProgressChanged` events. Also set property `WorkerReportsProgress` to `true`. Then start you first task asynchronously:

```
// this will execute code in `DoWork` event handler
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Next -  use `userState` object to pass processed words:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{      
    // grab words in a loop and report progress
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, word);
}
```

And last step - update label in `ProgressChanged` event handler

```
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text += (string)e.UserState; // this is your grabbed word
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, well I tried it, but I wasn't able to make it work.. I posted the Code.. Maybe u can help me?

Comment: @eMi actually your code should work. Verify if you subscribed to events correctly and that you are calling to `CreateAndSaveAMatch` method.

Comment: @eMi works just fine. I call `CreateAndSaveAMatch(DateTime.Now);` on button click. `DoWork` handler invoked, and progress reported with user state (btw you can simply return `e.Argument` here and convert it to string later). Then in `ProgressChanged` event my label is updated with current date. Are you sure you pasted complete code?

Comment: Ok I will try that tomorrow, maybe It's just not working in my Code-Context..(I had also an exception on backgroundworker1.RunWorkerAsynch(), that it is busy and I cant start it again (but I solved that, with: !backgroundwoker.IsBusy)) -- I will try to set up an easy Form with a Button like you.. Then I will try to adopt it to my application.

Comment: @eMi consider also to subscribe to `RunWorkerCompleted` event and verify if it is executed. Also you can check it's argument `e.Error` - if some Exception occurs during execution, it will be there.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this kind of thing is using BackgroundWorker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

BackgroundWorker automatically handles thread marshalling and provides events that allow you to update the UI.  The event handlers run on the UI thread.

The things you do in Task1 could be moved into a BackgroundWorker, and the updates to the UI that you propose to do in Task2 can actually be in response to progress events from BackgroundWorker.

[ProgressChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.aspx) provides for user-defined data that could hold the current word.

However, Winforms (and indeed pretty much any UI) will not be able to keep up with a separate CPU thread just loading words from a file if you intend to show every word you load.

Comment: thanks for your answer, well I tried it, but I wasn't able to make it work.. I posted the Code.. Maybe u can help me?

Answer (score 0):

`Task1` could be started on a separate thread.

You wouldn't actually need a `Task2` unless there was some complex logic being performed to update the TextBox. You you really need to do is use `TextBox.Invoke()` to invoke the update on the UI Thread from `Task1`.